# vh / % units and keyboard on mobile devices

Tags: css

I have problem with units like `vh` / `%` for heights. When any `input` is active, keyboard on mobile devices change elements height. I'm looking for solution to change it to static height when keyboard is active.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hxwhf715/show/) (open on mobile device)

Comment: Please add code + demo + screenshot of issue.

Comment: Try to set viewport size

Comment: maybe a fixed `min-height` along with mediaqueries could easily mitigate the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is quite straightfoward, we've all experienced it before.

Luckily I rarely work on websites that have elements that need to fit perfectly based on the viewport sizes, however when I do, I prefer to use a jQuery solution to achieve this.

I am going to go out on a limb and assume that you only need to apply this type of rule on mobile, so am going to add this to the code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ //wait for the DOM to load
    if($(window).width() > 640) { //check if screen width is less than 640px (i.e. mobile)
        $('#my-element').css({ 'height' : $(window).height() }); 
    }
});
```

It is possible to edit the height directly by changing the action to:

```
$('#my-element').height($(window).height());
```

but we specifically want to overwrite your CSS rule that stated something along the lines of:

```
#my-element { height: 100vh; }
```

[I've edited your codepen to include my example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXdBJj).